# Adding fade with img src swap

Tags: jquery, image, attr

Using alternate data attributes for image rollovers, as outlined here: [Best way to do image rollovers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260080/best-way-to-do-image-rollovers) and I can't figure out how to add a fade into attr swap.

Basically, on hover the img src changes, and that works perfectly.  But is there a way to make it fade in/out?

```
$(function(){
  $('img.rollover').hover(function(){
    var e = $(this);
    e.data('originalSrc', e.attr('src'));
    e.attr('src', e.attr('data-rollover'));
}, function(){
    var e = $(this);
    e.attr('src', e.data('originalSrc'));
}); /* a preloader could easily go here too */ 
});
```

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dtPRM/1/

Seems like a case for fadeToggle, but I've tried it in a couple places to no avail.

Also confused about the comma separated function on line six, though it seems to denote Not hovering.

Thanks

Comment: the comma separated function is the "hoverout-function" that gets executed when the mouse leaves the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just set the elements opacity to 0, then change img-src and then animate to opacity:1

```
$(function(){
$('img.rollover').hover(function(){
    var e = $(this);
    e.data('originalSrc', e.attr('src'));
    e.css('opacity',0);
    e.attr('src', e.attr('data-rollover'));
    e.animate({"opacity":1},400);
}, function(){
    var e = $(this);
    e.css('opacity',0);
    e.attr('src', e.data('originalSrc'));
    e.animate({"opacity":1},400);
}); /* a preloader could easily go here too */
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dtPRM/51/

Comment: Thats awesome, thanks!  When would fadeToggle make sense?  One of these days I'll get a handle on this...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3564K/)

In order to get a fade-out when mousing over, I animated a fadeout which had a callback that changed the source and then faded back in.

```
e.animate({opacity: 0},1000, function() {
    e.data('originalSrc', e.attr('src'));
    e.attr('src', e.attr('data-rollover'));
    e.animate({opacity: 1},1000);
});
```